# Identify default variables from less files

Tags: magento2, variables, less-css, less

I have a custom template with some variables set on _theme.less, it´s working fine. I need to remove "margin-bottom" from class named "sections nav-sections" but I cannot find this variable on ../lib/variables/*.less files. Tested a lot of variables with "margin" on their names without luck so far. I´m flushing the cache before testing. Any idea on how to identify the correct variable?

Answer (score 2):

**you can create a new variable for that set margin 0 it to.
magento\lib\web\css\source\lib\variables_typography.less**

```
in this file find following code. line no 67 approx

here is set default margin valuse you can new else write css 
sections .nav-sections { margin: @indent__base @indent__base 0 @indent__base; }


//
//  Indents
//  ---------------------------------------------

@indent__base: @line-height__computed; // 20px 
@indent__xl: @indent__base * 2; // 40px
@indent__l: @indent__base * 1.5; // 30px
@indent__m: @indent__base * 1.25; // 25px
@indent__s: @indent__base / 2; // 10px
@indent__xs: @indent__base / 4; // 5px
```